# Negative y axe in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make negative values on y-axe using

```
plt.yticks([10**(-8), 10**(-5), 10**(-2), 10, 10**(4)]) OR
plt.ylim([10**(-8), 10**(4)])
```

However, I have the following result:

[image: Graph]

Numbers are clustering together. This graph is a sample that I am looking forward to making :) 
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the scale of your y-axis logarithmic. Also, the values you are using are not negative. These are less than 1 and therefore the exponent is negative. Use

```
plt.yscale('log')
```